# Sidekiq strange behaviour of unique jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Well. I'm using Sidekiq to convert video files in background. I use [sidekiq-unique-jobs gem](https://github.com/form26/sidekiq-unique-jobs) to avoid jobs duplicating with the same payload object.

I run my sidekiq process with no options just in default queue with concurrency of 25.

The problem is: every job after being processed for a long time (video files are really big) goes to queue backlog but size of processed jobs is incrementing too.

Job is like neither completed nor unique. I'm stuck. Thanks in advance

UPD:

I'm running Puma as a web server.

Comment: Are these jobs taking longer than 30 minutes to complete?

Comment: Much longer than 30 minutes. 3-4 hours is average

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running it without the `sidekiq-unique-jobs` gem. It's only been protecting you against dupes for 30 minutes anyway. That gem sets its hashkeys in Redis to auto-expire after 30 minutes (configurable). `sidekiq` itself sets its jobs to auto-expire in Redis after 24 hours.

I obviously don't see your app, but I'll bet you want to not process the same file very often at all. I would control this at the application layer instead and track my own hashkey doing something similar to what the unique-jobs gem is doing:

```
hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Sidekiq.dump_json(md5_arguments))
```

It's also possible that the `sidekiq-unique-jobs` middleware is also getting in the way of `sidekiq` knowing if a job properly completed or not. I'll bet that there aren't a lot of folks testing this with long-running jobs in your same configuration.

If you continue to see this behavior without the additional middleware, give `resque` a try. I've never seen this kind of behavior with that gem, and failed jobs have a helpful retry option in the admin GUI.

The main benefit of sidekiq is that it is multi-threaded. Even so, a concurrency of 25 with large video processes might be pushing it a bit.  In my experience, forking is more stable and portable, with less worries about your application's thread-safety (YMMV).

Whatever you do, make sure that you are aware of the auto-expiry TTL settings that these systems put on their data in Redis. The size and nature of your jobs means that jobs could easily back up for 24 hours. These automatic deletions happen at the database layer. There are no callbacks to the application layer to warn if a job has been deleted automatically. In the `sidekiq` code, for example, they introduced auto-expire behavior to "to avoid any possible leaking." ( [reference](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md) ) This isn't very encouraging if you really need these jobs to execute.

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply. Actually, now I don't see this behavior anymore and the reason is still a little bit unclear. What I did: sure, I configured uniqueness expiration and set it up to 6 hours. I ran `redis-cli FLUSHALL` to clear all the jobs, because I had a habit to kill sidekiq processes unsafely (the reason of appearing old jobs). Also I configured `ffmpeg` using only 2 threads per job for converting and having only 3 sidekiq jobs running concurrently (I have 8 core processor on the server) and 25 concurrent ffmpeg jobs is too much for it, isn't it? :)

Comment: I know that there is no need to use sidekiq for this problem but I also use it for other kinds of jobs where I really can fell all its power and see that sidekiq is really effective. So I keep going on to use it even for video converting.

Comment: Forking another process may be more stable but it will also introduce lots of overload in performance. Running 25 concurrent jobs may be feasible now but if you're forking processes, you may only be able to run 5.